# <A HREF> + <DIV> combo not working on Google Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, html, href

I'm using an horizontal menu, with this html code:

```
<table class="tabellacontent">
    <tr>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Gen</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Feb</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Mar</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Apr</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Mag</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Giu</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Lug</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Ago</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Set</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Ott</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Nov</div></td></a>
        <a class="mesitab" href="link"><td><div class="tabmese">Dic</div></td></a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

​
With the following CSS:

```
.tabellacontent{
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:95%;
text-align:center;
}
.mesitab{
text-decoration:none;
}
.tabmese{
color:rgb(0,56,130);
margin:auto;
position:relative;
border:2px solid #000;
border-color:rgb(82,115,154);
width:100%;
height:15px;
top:1px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color:silver;
font-size:12px;
}
.tabmese:hover{
color:white;
background-color:rgb(49,87,132);
cursor: hand;
}​
```

My problem is that this code works on IE (7/8), but it does not work on Google Chrome.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Here there is a link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eT6Zm/3/)

Comment: What does it look like in chrome? What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: It's invalid HTML. You can't wrap `<td>` inside `<a>`.

Comment: Then why it works on IE7/8?

Comment: and you shouldn't put other tags except for a `<td>` inside of a `<tr>`

Comment: Because IE isn't exactly known for following standards.

Comment: @Juhana ok, so can you please explain me how I can do the same thing, with a valid HTML code?

Comment: `<td><div><a>whatever</a></div></td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `tr` should have its just child as `td` you have a wrong html.

**Solution** 
Place the `a` tag in the `td` and `div` tag then  make `padding` and `margin` of `div` to 0
then make a tag `display:block` to cover the entire td.

Answer (score -1):

I'm learning j-query mobile, and I found some troubles with href with chrome, the projeects don't run in local drive on chrome, you've got to upload to a server.